# Show onclick popupbox to specific id

Tags: javascript, jquery

[Like the one i have highlighted in picture popup box appear in every chatbox i want it to appear only on selected chatbox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gLbg6.jpg)

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
function make_chat_dialog_box(to_user_id, to_user_name)
{
  var modal_content = '<div id=user_dialog>..</div>';
  $('#user_model_details').append(modal_content);
  $(document).on("click", '.chat_message', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var to_user_id = $(this).data('touserid');
    $('.popupbox').css("display", "block");
    })
  }
});
</script>
```

Comment: Be sure that you bind your popup in specific id not in a class that used on more places.

Comment: can u please tell me how to bind my popup to specific id

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add id to your tag. and show popupbox only for that selected element.
Suppose you have textarea as a selector then your code should be.

```
<textarea class="popupbox" id="popupbox_ + to_user_id" ></textarea>
```

and in JS code

```
   <script>
     $(document).ready(function() {
      function make_chat_dialog_box(to_user_id, to_user_name) {
        var modal_content = "<div id=user_dialog>..</div>";
        $("#user_model_details").append(modal_content);
      }
      $(document).on("click", ".chat_message", function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var to_user_id = $(this).data("touserid");
        console.log(to_user_id); /** Make sure it is correct */
        $("#popupbox_"+to_user_id).css("display", "block");
      });
   });
  </script>;
```

Comment: can you provide an example?

Comment: You have another mistake in your code. I have updated my answer, please check it once again.